Understanding vfcpkc.b.s Instruction and Suffixes in Snitch's fp8_computation_vector Program
I'm exploring the fp8_computation_vector example from the Snitch repository and came across the following code snippet:
"fmv.s.x ft0, %0\n"
"fmv.s.x ft1, %1\n"
"fmv.s.x ft2, %2\n"
"fmv.s.x ft3, %3\n"
"vfcpka.b.s ft4, ft0, ft2\n"
"vfcpkb.b.s ft4, ft0, ft2\n"
"vfcpkc.b.s ft4, ft0, ft2\n"
"vfcpkd.b.s ft4, ft0, ft2\n"  // ft4 = {3.14, 1.618, 3.14, 1.618, 3.14, 1.618, 3.14, 1.618}

I have a few questions regarding the instructions:
What does the vfcpkc.b.s instruction specifically do in this context?
What is the significance of the suffixes .b, .a, or .ab when used in these instructions?
Are these suffixes related to data formats like FP8, and how do they influence the behavior of these vector operations?
Any clarification on how these instructions work in the context of Snitch and RISC-V vector programming would be helpful. Thanks!
